# $π = \frac{c}{d}$

Tags: irrational-numbers, pi

We know that $π = \frac{c}{d}$, where $c$ is circumference of circle and $d$ is diameter of circle. I surprised to see $π = \frac{c}{d}$ where $π$ is an irrational number and $\frac{c}{d}$ is rational number. Here  $c$ and $d$ are rational number.

What is a fact that I missed ?

Comment: $c=\pi d$ so are you sure that $c$ is a rational number? If we let $d=n/\pi$ for a rational $n$, then $c=n$ which is rational... but now $d$ is not rational no more.

Comment: Okey, we can construct a circle with any diameter that we want, so $d$ can be rational. How $c$ is rational in this case? Isn't.

Comment: Did you mean *circumference* where you typed *circumstance*?

Comment: $\displaystyle \pi = \frac{22}{7}$ close enough for an engineer.

Comment: $\frac cd$ is written as a fraction but it is not a fraction of *integers*.  If you don't know if $c,d$ are integers then you don't know that $\frac cd$ is rational.  A *rational* is number that can be expressed as a ratio between two *integers*.  As $c$ and $d$ are *never* both integers at the same time $\pi$ can be written as a ratio of two *non*-integers but not as a ratio of integers.  ....  $\frac cd$ is *not* a rational number because $c$ and $d$ are not both integers.

Comment: Note:   $\frac 2{\sqrt 2} = \sqrt{2}$ is not a rational number.  And $\frac e1 = e$ is not a rational number.  And $\frac {\pi}4$ is not rational.  And $\frac {\pi}1 = \pi$ is not rational.  Just because something can be written as a fraction does not mean it is a rational unless it can be written as a fraction *between integers* (and *none* of those examples can be).

Comment: "Here c and d are rational number."  That *never* happens.  *Ever*.  There is *no* circle in the universe where $c$ and $d$ are both rational.  It is impossible.  $c$ is *always* $\pi$ times whatever $d$ is.  If $d$ is rational, $c$ is not.  If $c$ is rational, $d$ is not.  Sometimes $d$ and $c$ are both irrational.  SOmetimes one is rational and the other is not.  But they are *NEVER* both rational.  Ever.